# Add OnEdit to a script or stop running script after it calculates cell in Google Sheets? Service invoked too many times Try Utilities.sleep(1000)

Tags: google-maps, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, spreadsheet

How to add OnEdit to a script or prevent script from running more than once in a particular Google Sheets cell? I'm using Google Maps to calculate time between 2 points but getting Service invoked too many times Try Utilities.sleep(1000).

The script I'm using:

```
/**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }

}
```

I would like the script to stop running on a particular spreadsheet cell once the value is calculated. 
Any thoughts?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Name").getRange("Select Range").activate();` at the end of your script.

Comment: Thank you, I added to my script so it looks like the below. Is the correct way you're suggesting or would I need to add the actual name of my sheet and range to your additional code like: SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(Sheet1).getRange(B:B).activate();

Comment: Yes you need to add the name of the sheet and range of the cell you want to end on.

Answer (score 0):

Or is this the correct way to add it? I added the code between the last 2 brackets and kept "Name" and "Select Range" text as is:

```
/**
* Get Distance between 2 different addresses.
* @param start_address Address as string Ex. "300 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param end_address Address as string Ex. "900 N LaSalles St, Chicago, IL"
* @param return_type Return type as string Ex. "miles" or "kilometers" or "minutes" or "hours"
* @customfunction
*/

function GOOGLEMAPS(start_address,end_address,return_type) {

  // https://www.chicagocomputerclasses.com/
  // Nov 2017
  // improvements needed

  var mapObj = Maps.newDirectionFinder();
  mapObj.setOrigin(start_address);
  mapObj.setDestination(end_address);
  var directions = mapObj.getDirections();

  var getTheLeg = directions["routes"][0]["legs"][0];

  var meters = getTheLeg["distance"]["value"];

  switch(return_type){
    case "miles":
      return meters * 0.000621371;
      break;
    case "minutes":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to minutes and return
        return duration / 60;
      break;
    case "hours":
        // get duration in seconds
        var duration = getTheLeg["duration"]["value"];
        //convert to hours and return
        return duration / 60 / 60;
      break;      
    case "kilometers":
      return meters / 1000;
      break;
    default:
      return "Error: Wrong Unit Type";
   }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Name").getRange("Select Range").activate();
}
```